# Using beautifulsoup to extract data from html content - HTML Parsing

Tags: regex, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

The contents of my script using beautifulsoup library is as follows:

```
 <meta content="Free" itemprop="price" />
```

and

```
 <div class="content" itemprop="datePublished">November 4, 2013</div>
```

I would want to pull the words Free and November 4, 2013 from that output.  Will using a Regex help or does beautifulsoup has any such attributes that will pull out this directly? Here is the code I used below:

```
   from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
   import urllib
   import re

   pageFile = urllib.urlopen("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.game.fifa14_na")
   pageHtml = pageFile.read()
   pageFile.close()

   soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(pageHtml))
   item = soup.find("meta", {"itemprop":"price"})

   print item
   items = soup.find("div",{"itemprop":"datePublished"})

   print items
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok got it! Just access the values by the following  method(for the above case):

```
   from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
   import urllib


   pageFile = urllib.urlopen("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.game.fifa14_na")
   pageHtml = pageFile.read()
   pageFile.close()

   soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(pageHtml))
   item = soup.find("meta", {"itemprop":"price"}) # meta content="Free" itemprop="price"
   print item['content']
   items = soup.find("div",{"itemprop":"datePublished"})
   print items.string
```

No need to add regex. Just a read up through the documentation would [help](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Why are you doing `soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(pageHtml))`